# avoid scaling scale the children of an element

Tags: css

I want to scale only the 'outer shell'

http://jsfiddle.net/97gSF/

```
.progress-radial:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}

<div class='progress-radial progress-100'>
    <div class='profilePicture'></div><a href='#' class='percent'>45%</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply counteract the scaling on the inner elements:

```css
.progress-radial:hover > * {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.833);
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/97gSF/2/).

Comment: Use scale(0.833)  instead of 0.85. 5/6 = 0.833 http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/97gSF/2/ .. .now it doesn't move

Comment: @Danield good shout, miscalculation on my part! I've updated the answer.

Comment: @RickiVandenbroek please see the amended answer. :)